# Adding OpenCV documentation to PyCharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I'm trying to simply add the OpenCV documentation to Pycharm so that I can quickly look up the documenation of any element I want to (SHIFT+F1).
For example,here's how wx has beens setup:

```
http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/{module.name}.{class.name}-class.html#{function.name}
```

I can't figure out how to do the same for the cv2 module.

Example URL: `docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#cv2.split`

Here The part in the middle `operations_on_arrays.html` is problematic as it's different for groups of functions.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm's external documentation feature can only build an URL from the name of the module and/or function for which the documentation is requested. If you need a more flexible structure of the URLs, the only way to support external documentation is by writing a plugin for PyCharm.

Comment: I understand, I was simply hoping that there would be an alternate reference URL to the OpenCV documentation pages whic h would involve only the module name and the function name.